# How do you create a dynamic select projection from a generic using Linq in C#?

Tags: c#, linq, select, projection

So I have a function that I pass Func call back to.  I would also like to add some sort of selection projection to be able to do the projection on the object, meaning I would only perform one database call.  The function looks something like this:

```
public T Get<T>(string id, Func<T> getItemCallback) where T : class
{
    item = getItemCallback();
    if (item != null)
    {
        doSomeThing(item);
        // Here I would like to call something else that is 
        // expecting a specific type.  Is there way to pass in a
        // dynamic selector?
        doSomethingElse(item.Select(x => new CustomType { id = x.id, name = x.name }).ToList());
    }
    return item;
}

void doSomethingElse(List<CustomType> custom)
{
    ....
}
```

Leme show how I cam currently calling this perhaps that will help:

```
public List<MyDataSet> GetData(string keywords, string id)
{
    return _myObject.Get(
       id, 
       () => db.GetDataSet(keywords, id).ToList());
    // Perhaps I could add another parameter here to 
    // handled the projection ????
}
```

Thanks to Reed I figured it out...would look like this:

```
public T Get<T>(string id, Func<T> getItemCallback, Func<T, List<CustomType>> selector) where T : class
{
     item = getItemCallback();
     if (item != null)
     {
          doSomething(item);
          var custom = selector(item);
          if (custom != null)
          {
              doSomethingElse(custom);
          }
     }
     return item;
 }
```

And The call looks like:

```
 public List<MyDataSet> GetData(string keywords, string id)
 {
     return _myObject.Get(
         id,
         () => db.GetDataSet(keywords, id).ToList(),
         x => x.Select(d => new CustomType { id = d.ReferenceId, name = d.Name })
               .ToList());
 }
```

Comment: It's not clear what exactly your problem is. Please try to be clearer.

Comment: It seems odd that you're getting a single item, but then doing "something else" on a `List<T>` of some other type...

Comment: Well the doSomething function expects just an object and it either logs it or caches it.  The doSomethingElse expects a list of items that I would define in the calling function not in the Get<T> function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to also pass in a conversion function:

```
public T Get<T>(string id, Func<T> getItemCallback, Func<T, List<CustomType>> conversion) where T : class
{
    item = getItemCallback();
    if (item != null)
    {
        doSomeThing(item);

        if (conversion != null)
            doSomethingElse(conversion(item));
    }
    return item;
}
```

Comment: If I am calling this Get<T> from 100's of db calls, wouldn't that mean I would have to account for the conversion of all of those types?  I am looking for a way to pass in a selector clause that I could apply to the already populated "item" object.

Comment: @ewahner Select would require that your type was `IEnumerable<Something>` - you're not giving us enough info to help (much) beyond what I'm showing.  This would let you pass a single lambda in that does the conversion, though.

Comment: I guess I would know whether or not the call to Get<T> was expecting an IEnumerable or just an object and would conditionally call the doSomethingElse.  So if I could somehow pass in a customer projection selector, if it were null I wouldn't call the doSomethingElse method.

Comment: @ewahner Then pass in a `Func<T, List<CustomType>>` - if it's null, don't call doSmoethingElse...

Comment: I agree with the answer provided by @ReedCopsey. Although, when you define the conversion function elsewhere and you are accessing specific properties of a generic object, you will either have to define some sort of interface or otherwise use reflection (the Interface approach being the safer approach).

Comment: But I want the List<CustomType> generated from the item with a custom projection, meaning it might be select(x => new { id = x.ReferenceId, name = x.Description }) and then the next proc that is called might have to be projected as select(x => new { id = x.orderno, name = x.CustomerName })

Comment: @ewahner Yes, so I'm saying pass that in as a `Func<T, List<CustomType>>` - that way, the caller can specify the projection operation

Comment: If my customer selector is null then I wouldn't make the call to doSomethingElse.  I wouldn't be able to make that evaluation on the List<CustomType>

Comment: Still not sure how to do that in my GetData call

Comment: Updated my problem thanks @Reed.  It was too simple to see.  Funny how as soon as I updated my Interface and went into my GetData call and just tabbed the autocomplete did half the work for me.